# iPhone HTTP Live Streaming not working on models below 3GS

Tags: iphone, video-streaming

We are using http live streaming for on demand video from within our iPhone app and on the 3GS models the videos play as they are meant to. However, on the models pre 3GS it gives an error saying this movie format is not supported.

I have seen other threads on this however no solutions or insights.

Does anyone know if this really is a hardware limitation of the pre 3GS phones or does it have something to do with our code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP Live Streaming is supported on all iPhone, iPod Touch and iPad hardware if you have sufficient network bandwidth for your lowest bit-rate stream and the right level of OS.  On an original iPhone 2G running iPhone OS 3.1.3 we are routinely playing HTTP Live Streams over WiFi.  It also works in our tests over Edge, but the bandwidth on Edge is usually too low for the rates at which we are encoding.   We have seen some issues with bandwidth adaptation on an iPod Touch running 3.1 which we suspect are related to that particular device/OS combination, but are not certain of that.

Answer (score 2):

"iPhone 3G supports H.264 Baseline Profile Level 3.1. If your app runs on older iPhones, however, you should use H.264 Baseline Profile 3.0 for compatibility."

Info taken from [this technote](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2224/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009745).